# Windows 7 USB setup freezes at logo on modern laptop

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, uefi

I want to use Windows Vista or 7 mostly because of its skin. I want to use it at my own risk. I've considered embedding it into a VM, like on Virtual Box, but I didn't get satisfied with it. My laptop is a [Samsung Essentials E20](https://compare.techtudo.com.br/produto/notebook-samsung-np350xbe-kdabr-celeron-4205u-1-80ghz-4gb-500gb-padrao-intel-hd-graphics-610-windows-10-home-essential-e20-15-6-polegadas-1110814) that came with Windows 10. I was able to download a disc image of Windows 7 x64 ([getmyos.com](https://www.getmyos.com/windows-7-ultimate-32-64-bit)) and integrated all of my Windows 10 drivers to the ISO by following this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rm1SiTF31IE).

I've confirmed the ISO works in a VM (Virtual Box). Now, when I run the USB setup in my computer rather than in VM, the setup freezes on Windows 7 logo. The USB flash drive gets forever in active use (green light).

I've read that some people are able to extract Windows 7 ISO targetting *legacy* system, with, say, Rufus, and they said it worked. In my case I've no such option, I can only choose UEFI:

[image: UEFI]

Secure Boot is disabled, I've confirmed.

Appreciate any tips.

Comment: what are your CPU architecture and the target architecture for the image you get?, if for example your CPU is arm or x86 only and the image is targeting x86_64 it wouldn't work , also try to enable legacy mode in your bios/uefi if you have it in your settings

Comment: @Mohab13 My architecture is x86_64 (x64 for short). This is the ISO name: `Windows_7_Ultimate_X64_SP1_En_Aug_2018.iso` I think I've looked my settings and there's no legacy option (only secure boot option).

Comment: and what is your CPU architecture?

Comment: @Mohab13 It's an Intel Celeron processor (x64).

Comment: @Mateus Dias de Souza i think you have to have legacy mode, also try disable tpm and secure boot , if it didn't work try another iso sometimes if unplug the usb incorrectly, it can lead to damaged data

Comment: You could see if anything found by googling for "windows 10 appearance like windows 7" is sufficient for you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Unfortunately the best I could do is get Windows 7 taskbar and start menu. Other parts I've not been able to do.

Comment: One possible reason why it freezes is because Windows 7 does not support UEFI GOP (Graphics Output Protocol) which is standard on a UEFI system. Though Windows 7 64 supports UEFI Boot, it lacks drivers for UEFI GOP. Just curious Is Partition Scheme disabled in Rufus? Can't you change it to MBR from GPT?

Comment: @patkim Yes, Partition Scheme can be set to MBR. I haven't tried it. Would it help?

Comment: Try setting it to MBR and see if you can get the other option to set it to BIOS + UEFI. However if your Laptop UEFI does not support Legacy mode, just in case, then this won't help. Even if it does, just in case,  you would still need to slipstream USB 3 drivers at a minimum in Windows 7.

Comment: @patkim I set it to MBR and Legacy still didn't show up. Anyway, I tried to install the ISO in MBR mode to the USB drive and the USB setup didn't show up in the list of bootable devices.

Comment: You may also try UEFI Seven https://github.com/manatails/uefiseven  but results vary from HW to HW. An EFI loader that emulates int10h interrupts needed for booting Windows 7 under UEFI Class 3 systems.

Answer (score 3):

To about 90%+ there is no chance to do what you want. Vendors (Microsoft has urged them) no longer allow Windows 7 or less to be installed on a modern machine.

You cannot do what you are trying to do.

In terms of GUI, you have 2 ways forward:

1. Use Gentoo and the Gentoo modules to get the GUI you want. Steep learning curve.
2. Adapt to Windows 10, or if your machine is new enough, update to Windows 11 and adapt to it.  That is the Windows way forward and that will not likely ever be like Windows 7 or Vista - both of which are gone.

Comment: So is that why my setup freezes (because the system prevents it)? Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: No. and that is because Windows 7 will not install.

Comment: It won't be worth the effort, even if you manage it. Win7 is dead & MS are trying hard to ensure it stays that way. It's completely unsafe to connect to the internet these days - there are well-known & well-used attack vectors out there just waiting for Win7 to connect.

Comment: Yes - everything prior to Windows 10 is not secure anymore

Comment: If you are concerned about GUI interface, best to adapt to the newer systems.

Comment: @John I was interested in forking Linux Mint Cinnamon to tweak it to look like Vista, but I don't know how to build ISO from their sources.

Comment: If you are really interested in trying Linux to suit your own tastes, Gentoo Linux is a "build your own Linux" system and is done with the modules they supply. That may assist you.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC problem was USB hub on motherboard. Flash driver worked pn USB 1.1 instead of 2.0. And booting was very long

Sorry for my Englidh...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).